# Custom keyboard の中で NSLocalizedString を読んでも .strings ファイルを読んでくれない

Tags: ios, localization, i18n

カスタムキーボードのコードの中で下記のように NSLocalizedString を呼び出していますが適切な `Localized.strings` を読んでくれず、常に英語になってしまい困っています。

```
data.append(NSLocalizedString("Notes", comment : "Event notes"))
```

それも英語の .strings ファイルを読んでいるわけではなく、単純に `NSLocalizedString` の引数の文字列（上で言う `"Notes"` ) を表示しているようです。

Localized.strings には `Base`, `English`, `Japanese` をそれぞれ追加しています。

Localized.stringsの画面
[image: Localized.strings]
[image: Localized.strings options]

プロジェクトの設定画面
[image: Project settings]

また info.plist の `primaryLanguage` には `mul` を設定して、シュミレーターと実機側の言語は日本語で、地域も日本語に設定してあります。

さらにチェックした方が良い箇所などアドバイスいただけるでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決。
Localized.strings と名付けてたが、 Localizable.strings と名付けないと、 NSLocalizedString で毎回ファイル名を指定ないといけないらしい。